# Why can't I read Ctrl+S in C?

Tags: c, input, io

I have this program in `C` that reads the input like this:

```
cod1 = getch ();
  if (kbhit())
    cod2 = getch ();
```

I can read every <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Char</kbd> possible sequences, except for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, that closes the program - that is OK, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, that simple is not catch. But I wanted to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to be the save function in my program; how could I do that? Furthermore, is it possible to read <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Char</kbd> characters? Because it reads it as a regular character, e.g., <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is read with the same codes as <kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: You probably have your tty configured so that Control-S = XOFF (suspend output).

Comment: Try to avoid using the conio.h library it isn't official and doesn't work in some IDES like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that input probably gets eaten by terminal emulator.

For example `Alt+<Whatever>` is often reserved for menu shortcuts (e.g. `Alt+F` opens `File` menu). Matching characters are often hilighted once you hold `Alt` (`F` get's underscored in `File`).

`Ctrl+S` [is reserved](http://www.computerhope.com/ushort.htm) for `Stops all output on screen (XOFF)` (again your terminal emulator does that).

As for using `Alt+<...>` as shortcuts in your command line application. As far as I'm concerned holding `Alt` doesn't affect character received, it just sets flags which are hard to access in console. Even in GUI application (in Windows) it's quite tricky and you have to use function like [`GetAsyncState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check whether alt was pressed.

Comment: Notice that you can turn off XON/XOFF in a terminal with `stty -ixon`.